# ParseQuery is not retrieving all data

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm making a Android application using Parse Server and I'm facing a sort of bug in the ParseUsers query. For some reason, when I make a `query.find()` to get all my data, is only getting one user, that is the one who is currently logged in (and it happens the same way if a log in as other user). The function looks like this:

```html
private void addContact(String contactNickname){ // TODO Bug en la query de usuarios
        //Se hace la consulta a la base de datos:
        try {
            ParseQuery<UserBO> usuarios = ParseQuery.getQuery(UserBO.class);
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> pruebaUsers = ParseUser.getQuery();
            //ParseQuery<ContactListBO> pruebaContactos = ParseQuery.getQuery(ContactListBO.class);
            //usuarios.whereEqualTo("username", contactNickname);
            usuarios.setLimit(5);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("USUARIOS ENCONTRADOS CON "+ contactNickname + ":");
            List<UserBO> resultados = new ArrayList<>();
            pruebaUsers.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (objects != null){
                        for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
                            System.out.println(objects.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            //List<ContactListBO> prueba = pruebaContactos.find();
            resultados = usuarios.find();
            System.out.println(resultados.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < resultados.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(resultados.get(i).toString());
            }
            /*for(int i = 0; i < prueba.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(prueba.get(i).getObjectId());
            }*/
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
//            UserBO contactoNuevo = resultados.get(0);
//
//            ContactListBO agregarContacto = new ContactListBO();
//            agregarContacto.setIdUser(currentUser.getObjectId());
//            agregarContacto.setIdContact(contactoNuevo.getObjectId());
//            agregarContacto.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
//                @Override
//                public void done(ParseException e) {
//                    if (e == null){
//                        onResponse("201");
//                    }else{
//                        onResponse("400");
//                    }
//                }
//            });

        } catch (ParseException parseException) {
            parseException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there are multiple queries, mostly because I was making tests, but the one I care about is `UserBO` query. Reading you will see a query of `ContactListBO` and that query works totally fine, but I do the same thing with `UserBO` query and I'm getting only 1 of my 3 users, like this:

```
UserBO{id=vluB9loAHe, UniqueUsername='prueba1', CompleteName='testUno', Password=null}
```

As I say, it only gets the current logged in user and I need to get all my users. If you need it, here is UserBO.java:

```html
package co.com.signchat.co.com.signchat.entity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

@ParseClassName("_User")
public class UserBO extends ParseUser {

    private static final String id = "objectId";
    private static final String completeName = "NombreCompleto";
    private static final String uniqueUsername = "username";
    private static final String password = "password";

    //FOTO DE PERFIL
    private String base64profilePicture;
    private String base64miniProfilePicture;
    private Bitmap profilePictureBitmap;

    private int user_state_id;




    //GETTERS Y SETTERS

    //id
    public String getId(){return getObjectId();}
    public void setId(int id){
        put(this.id, id);
    }

    //completeName
    public String getCompleteName(){return getString(completeName);}
    public void setCompleteName(String completeName){
        put(this.completeName, completeName);
    }

    //uniqueUsername:
    public String getUniqueUsername(){return getUsername();}
    public void setUniqueUsername(String uniqueUsername){
        put(this.uniqueUsername, uniqueUsername);
    }

    //password
    public String getPassword(){return getString(password);}
    public void setPassword(String password){
        put(this.password, password);
    }

    //base64profilePicture
    public void setBase64profilePicture(String base64profilePicture){
        this.base64profilePicture = base64profilePicture;

        byte[] byteCode = Base64.decode(base64profilePicture, Base64.DEFAULT);
        this.profilePictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteCode, 0, byteCode.length);
    }
    public String getBase64profilePicture(){
        return this.base64profilePicture;
    }

    public Bitmap getProfilePictureBitmap() {
        return profilePictureBitmap;
    }

    //user_state_id
    public int getUser_state_id(){return this.user_state_id;}
    public void setUser_state_id(int user_state_id){
        this.user_state_id = user_state_id;
    }

    //base64miniProfilePicture
    public String getBase64miniProfilePicture() {return base64miniProfilePicture;}
    public void setBase64miniProfilePicture(String base64miniProfilePicture) {
        this.base64miniProfilePicture = base64miniProfilePicture;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserBO{" +
                "id=" + getId() +
                ", UniqueUsername='" + getUniqueUsername() + '\'' +
                ", CompleteName='" + getCompleteName() + '\'' +
                ", Password=" + getPassword() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

These are all my users in my database, which I'm using PostgresSQL

[image: These are all my users in my database, which I'm using PostgresSQL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image attached to your question explains the behaviour you're facing. We can see that ACL column you have on User class is allowing read and write only to user that's associated with the record.

You have two options to solve this:

1. You could make logic that some specific role or user has rights for reading all of the users in database. In the application you should then be authenticated with this role/user in order to be able to read all user data.
2. Write cloud code that will get you all the users. Make sure to use `useMasterKey` option to override object and class access permissions.

```javascript
Parse.Cloud.define('fetchAllUsers', () => {
  // Create new query from user class
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
  // Return the result of query
  return query.find({ useMasterKey: true })
})
```

Function can be then called from client using Parse SDK built-in methods.

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you! I choose using Parse Cloud and it works.